# Анимация в котлин

Tags: kotlin, анимация

Всем привет!Подскажите, как сделать простейшую анимацию из двух кадров в Android_studio и вызвать ее в коде с помощью kotlin?

[image]
[image]

Вот,например, из этого сделать вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот анимацию готового объекта разобрался как сделать(Такое как вращение, увеличение и т.д.)
А чтобы один кадр менял другой не пойму.
Нашел одну статью про создание XML файла и добавлении туда своих картинок, но она не полная и не совсем понятно, что в какую папку положить и как обратиться к этому файлу

Comment: Я почти уверен, что у Вас проблема [молотка и микроскопа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/Что-такое-Ошибка-молотка-или-Ошибка-xy?rq=1). Покадровая анимация - почти всегда плохо для производительности и веса приложения. Нужны **веские** основания, чтобы делать то, что Вы хотите. Объясните, почему выбрали именно такую анимацию

Comment: А как реализуют покадровые анимации в андроид разработке? Например, анимация шагающего человека, где первый кадр-стоит, а второй-нога вперед

Comment: Обычно это делают с помощью Lottie анимаций, эти анимации на самом деле не совсем покадровые. Или можно использовать гиф, если уж на то пошло

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно. Lottie

Comment: Вот возможно то, что вы ищите https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation